# SSH proxy tunnel hop

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy

My situation is like this, I have Server A  which has internet

I have server B which is behind a firewall and can`t connect to the internet but I can access it thru SSH

Then I have server C D E that are in the same network as server B but they can only be accessed from server B thru SSh

I am able to give internet thru ssh tunnel proxy from server A to server B   using ssh -R and then connecting back using -D from server B to A to set a port that I can use as proxy.

I kept searching on google for this issue but I couldn`t find my exact situation.

I want to be able to give internet thru one socks5 port to server C D E from server B or A if possible.

How would I go about doing that ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server A, create a SSH connection to B, use B as a jump host to C, open a reverse SOCKS connection:

```
ssh -J B -R PORT C
```

- `-J B` use `B` as jump host
- `-R PORT` reverse proxy on `PORT`, requires a recent version of ssh

For details, see the manual.